# twine upload fails when using a proxy server

Tags: python-3.x, pip, http-proxy, pypi, twine

I can't upload to `pypi` using `twine` when a proxy server is involved.

That's what I tried so far:

```
python -m twine upload -u USER -p PASSWORD dist/*
```

When I'm behind our company proxy server `twine` just hangs, no error message.
Set the `https_proxy` and the`http_proxy` environment variables doesn't help as well.

Our company proxy server has it's own CA certificate (I've the `.cer` file).

So how can I use `twine` behind a proxy server.

With `pip` I was able to do it by adding the following `pip.ini` file to `%Appdata%\pip`:

```
[global]
proxy = proxy.company.com:8080
cert = C:\CA_Proxy.cer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `HTTPS_PROXY` and `TWINE_CERT` environment variables in command prompt before running `twine` solve the problem:

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.company.com:8080
set TWINE_CERT=C:\CA_Proxy.pem

python -m twine upload -u USER -p PASSWORD dist/*
```

Remark: make sure that the certificate is in the `PEM` (Base-64 encoded X.509) format.

See the twine user manual for the `TWINE_CERT` environment variable
https://twine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to solve a similar issue under Windows by setting an `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable, without having to set anything about certificates.

Working in a `cmd` prompt, run

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.company.com:8080
```

before running your `twine` command in the same session.

The environment variable can also be set permanently using the control panel or as described in https://superuser.com/q/79612/1148425

Comment: It doesn't work: `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='upload.pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /legacy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:841)'),))`

Comment: `set TWINE_CERT=C:\CA_Proxy.pem` solves the problem. Make sure the certificate is in the PEM format.